# JavaFX 3D depth rendering incorrectly

Tags: java, javafx-8

Setup:
The following code, renders a 3D scene with a visible co-ordinate axis positioned at the origin, from a camera displaced by -156 units in the Z direction. Also, the camera's Z position is a function of mouse scroll, such that scrolling up/down will move the camera further/closer from the origin.

Problem:
upon initial startup of the program, the red and green axis are rendered at/near the origin, when in the physical world, it would be impossible to see them there from the current camera view. (blue axis blocking them). Also, when you scroll backwards and forwards, you can see glitches/flashes where the red/green axis are visible behind the blue axis, which should not occur.

Screenshot of result (with my manual adding of issue description):
[initial_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x435r.png)

Question:
1) Is this a problem with my setup? or JavaFX?
2) if this is a problem with my setup, then can someone please explain what I can do to remedy this issue?

Code:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testproblemjavafx01;

/**
 *
 * @author ad
 */

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Camera;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestProblemJavaFX01 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        buildAxes(root);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);       

        scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        camera.setNearClip(0);
        camera.setFarClip(1000.0);

        camera.setTranslateX(0);
        camera.setTranslateY(0);
        camera.setTranslateZ(-156); 

        scene.setCamera(camera);
        setMouseEvents(scene);

        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TestProblemJavaFX01");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void buildAxes(Group root) {
        final PhongMaterial redMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
        redMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.DARKRED);
        redMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.RED);

        final PhongMaterial greenMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
        greenMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.DARKGREEN);
        greenMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.GREEN);

        final PhongMaterial blueMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
        blueMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.DARKBLUE);
        blueMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.BLUE);

        final Box xAxis = new Box(240.0, 1, 1);
        final Box yAxis = new Box(1, 240.0, 1);
        final Box zAxis = new Box(1, 1, 240.0);

        xAxis.setMaterial(redMaterial);
        yAxis.setMaterial(greenMaterial);
        zAxis.setMaterial(blueMaterial);

        root.getChildren().addAll(xAxis, yAxis, zAxis);
    }

    private void setMouseEvents(final Scene scene) {
    scene.setOnScroll(
            new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
              @Override
              public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                double deltaY = event.getDeltaY();

                Camera camera = scene.getCamera();
                camera.setTranslateZ(camera.getTranslateZ() + deltaY);
                event.consume();
              }
            });
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an InvocationTarget exception with your code.  Maybe the launch process is looking for a method you don't show?

Comment: This is the complete code. If I open a new project in NetBeans and paste in then it compiles and runs fine. If there's something I've left out then it is being introduced behind the scenes by NetBeans. I'm using JDK1.8 also.

Comment: Yes, I had to use "New JavaFx Application".  A standard Java project won't work.  Thanks for the help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is within the line `camera.setNearClip(0);`

From the documentation of [setNearClip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Camera.html#setNearClip-double-):

> Specifies the distance from the eye of the near clipping plane of this
>   Camera in the eye coordinate space. Objects closer to the eye than
>   nearClip are not drawn. nearClip is specified as a value **greater than
>   zero**. A value less than or equal to zero is treated as a very small
>   positive number.

Try to set the value to its default value of `0.1`. Or just remove the line.